# Computing autocorrelation of scalar values

Tags: plotting, curve-fitting

I obtained a list of $r^2_{end-to-end}$ from a Monte Carlo simulation of polymer movement.

```
#r-end-squared
58617.14512069625
55606.1082220041
51244.724846185505
65344.140277928964
63392.17236605068
62101.375689808614
58814.8832777033
60040.00627213609
52019.130880313125
56984.44642212785
... ... ... ...
```

I want to compute autocorrelation, then fit an exponential decay curve on the 2D XY plane, and finally obtain the best fit values (fitx, fity).

What fomula can I use for autocorrelation?

---

The autocorrelation formula used in the case of $r^2_{end-to-end}$ is as follows:

$$ R(t) = \frac{1}{(n - t) \cdot \sigma^2} \sum_{i=0}^{n-t-1} (X_i - \mu)(X_{i+t} - \mu) $$

where:

- $( n )$ is the number of observations in the dataset,
- $( t )$ is the lag, or the distance between the compared points,
- $( \mu )$ is the mean of the dataset,
- $( \sigma^2 )$ is the variance of the dataset,
- $( X_i )$ and $( X_{i+t} )$ are the data points at indexes $( i )$ and $( i+t )$ respectively.

The autocorrelation value $( R(t) )$ for each lag $( t )$ is calculated by summing the product of the mean-adjusted data points separated by the `lag`, and then normalizing the sum by dividing it by the product of the variance and the number of terms in the sum (adjusted for the lag). This calculation is done for each lag from 0 up to the specified number of lags (`numLag`), but not exceeding the number of data points (`n`). The computed autocorrelation values are then filtered based on the specified thresholds (`thresholdMin` and `thresholdMax`).

However, I am not sure about it at all.

Comment: What have you already done? Have you looked up the formula for autocorrelation somewhere? Have you checked whether it is implemented n any of the software systems you re using?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, Do you want to see my used formula or Python source code?

Comment: OK, so you have a formula. That answers your question. What do you still want to know?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, I want to know if this formula is correct or not.

Comment: Well, that's a strange question. Where do you have it from? Why don't you trust the source where you have that formula from?